# List usage without specifying the Type

Tags: java, hibernate, list, generics, entities

I see a code in the new environment. It is as follows:

```
List results;

if (<Some Condition>) {
    results = List<XYZ> results;
} else {
    results = List<ABC> results;
}
```

`XYZ` and `ABC` are Hibernate Entities.
Though this works, I guess this is not a proper way to do this.

I would like to know whats the better way to do it. I know there is no "perfect" way to do it. But this can be better.

Remember these are non-similar Entities. So I think wrapping these Entities with an Interface might not be a good idea.

Comment: Hard to say from just those lines. Maybe divide it up to two methods so the same code doesn't handle two different entities.

Comment: @Kayaman I thought of the separate methods already. But is there a better way without doing it. Something with generics `List<T>` etc? What more info you need?

Comment: I doubt generics will help here. If a piece of code is handling two types of unrelated objects depending on a condition, then that code or method is probably trying to do too much. The code you posted however doesn't show anything useful about the design, beyond the simplified example.

Comment: why not use wildcard List<?>?

Comment: second of all you can't do what you are doing , it should be instantiated and not with the interface List, something like results=new ArrayList<XYZ>();

Comment: You should really have two separate `List` objects for this, then only instantiate the one that meets `Some Condition`.  Don't forget to do a null check before continuing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics are a compile-time mechanism, so, if you don't know the type of object you are pulling, generics are not appropriate.

I understand that the entities are different and not correlated, but I don't understand why an interface is not a good idea. Basically, you know that you want to collect some data, according to some condition. So, just for the fact that XYZ and ABC are candidates to be type of the collected data, you do have some commonalities. In that case, you may have a

```
List<? extends CommonInterface>
```

and CommonInterface is used just here.

However, assuming XYZ and ABC are completely distinct, one more option could be to split the method in two parts and use a generic method receiving also the type of data you want to collect:

```
public void methodForTheCondition() {
    if (<some condition>) {
        List<XYZ> l = genericMethod(XYZ.class);
        // do something
    } else {
        List<ABC> l = genericMethod(ABC.class);
        // do something else, which I assume is different, otherwise opt for
        // a common interface
    }
}

public <T> List<T> genericMethod(Class<T> clazz) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: My following questions: Is one of what you mentioned above is the right way to do it or the way I posted is okay too, in terms of standard / good programming practice?

Comment: The method you posted doesn't leverage the generics compile-time type checking; in fact you are probably having a warning like "List is a raw type". This means that you are allowed to add any object into the list and no compile errors will arise, but then runtime exception will be an issue for sure. On the other side, I would say that both ways I proposed are acceptable. Their use depends on the specific situation: if a reasonable common interface exists, then you definitely want to use generics with the wildcard (?), as this enables the use of polymorphism. Otherwise I'd say generic method

Answer (score 1):

> But this can be better.

What makes you believe this? Without knowing the *exact* condition, this looks simply like a mass-loading of items in a generic EntityManager and therefore returning a `List<X>` whatever `X` might be.

From the code point of view, there is nothing wrong, because you are creating a untypted List and assigning a List of a certain type to that variable later...

As long as you use `List` as a raw-type, you are able to assign any List to it. This is what interfaces are designed for (Assigning a type without knowing the *exact* type...)

> Remember these are non-similar Entities. So I think wrapping these Entities with an Interface might not be a good idea.

There are a *lot* of Interfaces out there that makes perfect sence for non-similar Items. Starting with anything that Aggregates elements (List, Map), ending with Interfaces that simply describe **one** thing that is in common, I.E: `Serializable`, `Comparable`, etc..

An *Interface* does not mean that the objects are related in some way (that is what parent/abstract classes are used for) An Interface simply say that a *certain* functionality is **implemented.** (hence, you can inherit multiple interfaces in one class)

Comment: The problem with interface here is this: Lets say `XYZ` type has a method, `xyzMethod()`, and ABC has a method `abcMethod()`, how do you invoke these type specific methods, if you wrap these with interface and use List<Interface>?